# Decompressing gzip content-encoding using Python3

Tags: python, python-requests, gzip

I am making a call to a client's data store which returns the following response:

```
{'error_code': 0, 'message': 'Success', 'request_id': '409d2f00c02fb8a069c97cfe5f6992c1', 'data': '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'}
```

Headers are:

```
{'Server': <server>, 'Date': 'Sun, 30 Jul 2023 11:31:36 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-trace-id': '-', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '0', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization,Language,Src,X-Client-Signature,X-Client-Appid,X-Client-Local-Time,X-Requested-With,X-Request-Timestamp,x-client-authorization,content-type,Locale,X-Client-Uhomes,Version,X-Channel-Source,X-Uhouzz-Cust-ID,X-Request-Xcode,X-Uhouzz-Device-Id,X-Client-Aprid,X-Client-Xcode,baggage,sentry-trace,X-Client-Deviceid', 'Access-Control-Max-Age': '259200'}
```

I am confused at the combination of:

```
'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
```

and

```
'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
```

What is the best way to go about decompressing the response.json()['data'] string?
gzip/zlib methods only take a byte object, and converting this string to a byte object yields an error suggesting that the content is not, in fact, gzip encoded!

Any pointers would be much appreciated!